# Is it recommended to use Kafka as a source of truth?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-storm

Our application requires a very high write throughout (several thousand writes per second during peak bursts) and the data needs to go into several data-stores like Elastic-Search, HDFS, Cassandra and Cache. (No relational DB thankfully).

What is the best way to handle this?

Is it a good idea to have Kafka as a source of truth from where all the other data-stores can read (via Spark/Storm streaming)?

Is there a potential for data-loss with Kafka?
Is that potential for data-loss any greater than writing directly to Cassandra?

EDIT: One problem I do see is that the constraints imposed by Cassandra are different from those imposed by Kafka. Since Kafka imposes no constraints and will accept any data, it might give the application a false sense of successful transaction by writing to Kafka. The same data might not succeed in Cassandra due to some constraint violation in Cassandra. Example constraint failure from Cassandra: `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid INTEGER constant (500) for "name" of type text"`. It is possible that the application experiences a change in some data-type and Kafka is happily accepting it while downstream Cassandra consumer is failing. (How that change will pass staging, qa phases etc. is a different story). So the risk of using Kafka as a source of truth is that it gives a false sense of success.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a good idea to have Kafka as a source of truth from where all the other data-stores can read

Absolutely. Kafka was design for this pattern in the first place. Even in Kafka is more then just message brokers/pub-sub system in the meantime, also adding Stream processing capabilities in Kafka 0.10.

> Is there a potential for data-loss with Kafka?

Not after your data got acked. In Kafka, you can either write synchronously or asynchronously, and you can configure how many broker should have replicated your data before you receive an "ack" on the producer. Compare http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/producer.html

> Is that potential for data-loss any greater than writing directly to Cassandra?

I am not familiar with Casandra in detail, but I don't think that Casandra provides stronger fault-tolerance that Kafka -- it all boils down to the number of replicas you configure (and you can do that for both Casandra and Kafka).

*About potential corrupted data in Kafka:* Kafka does not inspect any written data and only deals with `byte[]` on the broker side. So yes, your should apply strategies on your producers to ensure no corrupted data is written into a topic. However, you could for example use AVRO as your data type, and it will help you to guard agains corrupted data.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. `your should apply strategies on your producers to ensure no corrupted data is written into a topic` - This is very hard to do actually because downstream systems can have a myriad of constraints, some of them which might be checked only by the downstream system. For example: if downstream system is a relation DB, it might be doing some foreign key checks or unique key checks. Those checks can be done only by the actual downstream tool.

Comment: Yes. But if different downstream system have different constraint, no system can enforce all those constrains in a perfect way -- either is would apply the strongest constrain (and thus limited some consumer) or is applies the weakest constrain and some downstream system require stronger constraints. The idea of Kafka is, to decouple producers and consumers -- a producer should not dictate in which way a consumer processed the data. Thus, each consumer should apply it's own constraints on the data and just drop data that does not meet the contraint it needs.

Comment: If you use the DB key-example: if you try to enforce this on the producer side, a consumer that does not care about foreign key constraint gets limited -- it will only receive data that does meet the constraint. At the same time, the DB can just drop (and not insert) data that does not meet the FK constraint. Furthermore, how does the producer or the intermediate system know what constraint downstream producers do have?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my point. Basically, the question is about using Kafka as a source of truth. Common sources of truth are DBs like MySQL or Cassandra. So I was trying to enumerate the issues one might encounter when they replace their DB-source-of-truth with Kafka. It is not a Kafka limitation, probably a design flaw to replace the DB-source-of-truth with Kafka because of the above issue. Hence also the comment that it is difficult to enforce all the SOT constraints upfront in Kafka-producer code.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Kafka is more or less to capture "raw data". In this sense, if you have a FK constraint, Kafka would capture the fact that somebody tried to insert something into a DB -- if a consumer DB rejects this insert it's independent of this "raw fact" that somebody tried to do this. If DB is "source of truth" the user is informed that the insert failed, but the "fact" that the user tried to insert is lost. Kafka would capture this fact and you need a way to communicate back to the user (maybe another topic) if the DB insert was successful or not.

Comment: So it boils done to a design decision. But yes, you can use Kafka as "source of truth" :)

Comment: sure, but one should remember the above when trying to replace their existing "source of truth" database and be prepared to fix/face the constraint issues when doing the replace.